# how to store variable in shared memory

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory

I am trying to add the variable bank into shared memory to explore race conditions and process synchronization using semaphores. When I setup the variable in shared memory my program gives me segmentation fault:11. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here and how I can go about fixing this? Thanks!

**RACE**

```
    #include <unistd.h> 
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h>  
    #include <sys/mman.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <semaphore.h>

    int shmid;
    int shmkey = 585858;
    sem_t mutex; // semaphore global variable

    struct Bank {
        int balance[2];
    };

    struct Bank *bank;

    // routine for thread execution
    void* MakeTransactions() { 
        int i, j, tmp1, tmp2, rint;
        double dummy;

        // wait on semaphore
        //sem_wait(&mutex);
        for (i=0; i < 100; i++) {  
            rint = (rand()%30)-15; 
            if (((tmp1=bank->balance[0])+rint) >=0 &&
            ((tmp2=bank->balance[1])-rint)>=0) { 
                //sem_wait(&mutex);
                bank->balance[0] = tmp1 + rint;
                //sem_post(&mutex); 
                for (j=0; j < rint*100; j++) {
                    dummy=2.345*8.765/1.234; // spend time on purpose
                }
                //sem_wait(&mutex);
                bank->balance[1] = tmp2 - rint;
                //sem_post(&mutex); 
            }  
        } 
        // increment value of semaphore
        //sem_post(&mutex);
        return NULL; 
    } 

    int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

        int i;
        void* voidptr = NULL;

        // initialize semaphore
        sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

        // shared memory
        //bank = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct Bank), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
        // create shared memory 
       shmid = shmget(shmkey, 1024, IPC_CREAT);
       // attach to shared memory
       bank = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);


        //check if bank is not NULL
        bank->balance[0] = 100;
        bank->balance[1] = 100;

        pid_t pid;
        srand(getpid()); 

        printf("\nInit balances A:%d + B:%d ==> %d!", 
        bank->balance[0],bank->balance[1],bank->balance[0]+bank->balance[1]); 

        pid=fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed");
            return 1;
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("\nChild computing ...");
            MakeTransactions();
            printf("\nChild process complete");
            printf("\nLet's check the balances A:%d + B:%d ==> %d ?= 200",
                bank->balance[0],bank->balance[1],bank->balance[0]+bank->balance[1]);
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("\nParent computing...\n");
            MakeTransactions();
            wait(NULL);
            printf("\nParent process complete\n");
            printf("Let's check the balances A:%d + B:%d ==> %d ?= 200\n\n",
                bank->balance[0],bank->balance[1],bank->balance[0]+bank->balance[1]);
            return 0;
        }
        sem_destroy(&mutex);
        // deattach shared memory pointer
        shmdt(&bank,NULL);
        //munmap(bank, sizeof(struct Bank));
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Sure that will create a race condition. That's the point of the mutex.

Comment: `for (j=0; j < rint*100; j++) { dummy=2.345*8.765/1.234; // spend time on purpose }` The compiler will probably optimize this out for you so be care full.

Comment: your code, as it stands does NOT compile. e.g. what's `&shmpointer` in `shmdt` it's supposed to be `bank`

Comment: @AhmedMasud Sorry I forgot to make that edit. That's what I have (should compile) but it gives a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

Okay the reason it gives you a segfault is because you're probably running this program as an unprivileged user. `shmat` requires privileges. If you are running it under linux you can do this:

> sudo setcap cap_ipc_owner=ep ./myprog

to enable it to call `shmat` etc.

and then run it.

You would've found out about this if you had added a bit of error handling:

```
   shmid = shmget(shmkey, 1024, IPC_CREAT);
   if (shmid == -1 ) {
       perror("shmget");
       exit(errno);
   }
   // attach to shared memory
   bank = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

   if (bank == (void *)-1) {
       perror("bank");
       exit(errno);
   }
```